# Instantiating a prefab at the mouse position for my sandbox game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't manage to instantiate a prefab at my mouse position.

I've tried to instantiate the prefab at the current mouse position, but on click, the block shows in the hierarchy and not the scene. It also creates 4-5 prefabs.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject block;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Instantiate(block, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create 1 prefab of the block, and I want it to show up in the scene view.

Answer (score 2):

Input.mousePosition is the coordinates of the mouse on the screen. Use Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint to get the world position.

The block will not show in the scene, because its position is likely something like (500, 300, 0), which is very far. Select the block in the Hierarchy and press "F" to see it.

Input.GetMouseButton() keeps firing as long as the mouse is held. Change this to Imput.GetMouseButtonDown()

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Building : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject block;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Instantiate(block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it gave me this error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object Building.cs:11

Comment: Make sure that block is assigned in the Inspector tab

Comment: Also make sure that you are in the Game view, and that there is a camera

Comment: Make sure that your camera is tagged "MainCamera"

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from screen space to world space.

One way to do this is to use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html):

```
private Camera mainCam;

void Start()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 blockPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        Instantiate(block, blockPos, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

If you want to spawn further away from the camera, look into [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html).